# "an" oder "für" im Satz?

Tags: grammar, preposition

> Die Bewerber waren offen und sehr interessiert **an** neuen Arbeitsmarktperspektiven in Deutschland.

Warum nutzt man *an* und nicht *für?*

Der Satz kann [hier](http://www.goethe.de/ins/gr/de/lp/kul/dug/pok/bub/11806547.html) gefunden werden.

Comment: Du wirst vermutlich eine zufriedenstellendere Antwort erhalten, wenn Du erklärst, warum Du *für* verwendet hättest.

Comment: Aus dieser Frage **kann** man eine sehr gute und allgemeingültige Frage machen. Erstens fehlt der Hinweis (ich gehe davon aus, dass du es weißt), dass es "*für* etwas offen sein" und "*an* etwas interssiert sein" heißt. Im Beispiel werden dann die beiden Phrasen durch "und" verknüpft. Und die allgemeingültige Frage lautet dann: Was macht man in solchen Fällen? Welche Präposition wird verwendet? Erstere, letztere, oder gar beide? – Man sollte dann an der Stelle auch darauf achten, dass "neu" anders dekliniert würde, wenn dort "für" stände: "offen für neue Perspektiven"

Comment: Der gleiche Satz mit "für" kann [hier](http://www.dsathen.gr/de/schulleben/griechisch-deutscher-sport-und-kulturverein/doc_view/1010-berufsboerse-bilanztexte)  gefunden werden.

Comment: @Em1... ich fürchte das ist eine reingelesene Interpretation. Das "und" kann auch zwei Eigenschaften verbinden,nämlich "offen" und "interessiert an", und ich glaube so ist es auch gemeint, da "ich bin offen für neue Arbeitsmarktperspektiven" für mich nicht so viel Sinn macht.

Comment: @Em1: Darauf, dass man wegen *offen **für** etw. sein* darauf kommen könnte, hier *für* zu nutzen, bin ich tatsächlich nicht gekommen – was aber daran liegen könnte, dass es hier tatsächlich keinen Sinn ergäbe (was allerdings zugegebenermaßen nicht einfach zu erkennen ist).

Comment: Oh. "offen für" ergibt hier in der Tat keinen Sinn. Ich nehme alles zurück und behaupte das Gegenteil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Auch wenn es heißt

> Ich interessiere mich für...

so ist

> Ich bin interessiert an...

doch eine andere Formulierung und der Infinitiv "interessiert sein" braucht "an" einfach... weil. Das hat sich so entwickelt und nun ist "an" idiomatisch und "für" nicht ([n-Gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=interessiert%20an%2C%20interessiert%20f%C3%BCr&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinteressiert%20an%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinteressiert%20f%C3%BCr%3B%2Cc0)), während es für "sich interessieren" anders ist.